# Bootstrap - Progress bar as background in card element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate something like the image below (the dark one), that looks like a progress bar in every element of a card. I'm getting close but the problem I have so far is that the text moves with the progress bar.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item progress-bar bg-success" style="width:40%"><a>Cras justo odio</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item progress-bar bg-info" style="width:100%">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item progress-bar bg-warning" style="width:10%">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: My result so far]

This is the goal, how can I make it?

[image: Progress bar in card elements]

Comment: Would it be because you are styling the actual list item to 40% which contains your <a>....</a> information?

Comment: Could you post a fiddle of the issue? Might help us see where the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your inline style, add: text-align: left; padding-left: 10px;
like as follows:

```
<li class="list-group-item progress-bar bg-warning" style="width:10% text-align: left; padding-left: 10px;">Vestibulum at eros</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add text align to the list item

`.list-group-item {
        text-align: left;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth considering a slightly different approach, because by using list items you're quite likely to break Bootstrap's javascript and accessibility and will be much harder to animate if you wish to do so later.

Instead you could simply re-style Bootstrap's progress bars to look exactly how you want.

```
<style>
     .progress {
          overflow-y: hidden; height: 40px; padding: 0; border-radius: 0; border: 1px solid #252830; background-color: #434857;
     }
     .progress-bar {
          height: 40px; overflow: visible; background-color: rgb(52, 125, 241); font-size: 1.3em; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px; border-radius: 0;
     }
</style>

<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"  style="width: 95%;">United States</div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 5%;">India</div>
</div>
```

This example also adds overflow: visible; to progress-bar so that the labels don't clip.